# Move documents from O3Spaces to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, document, ecm, document-migration

I am getting ready to move from O3Spaces to Sharepoint2010, is there any way to migrate documents(and their versions and comments, hopefully) from O3Spaces to Sharepoint?

Comment: What is the number and size of documents you are trying to migrate to SP?

Comment: What is the type of documents?

Comment: I wish I could say, but I am not sure. I am an intern here, they've tasked me with finding the best way to do this. I'm going out on a limb and assuming they're mostly all going to be excel documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not worked with O3Spaces. But, looking from the SP point of view, you have the following options:

- Use the SharePoint 2010 object model.
- Use the O3Spaces API.
- As Falak mentioned, try a third-party tool to migrate the data into SP. For example, [FileLoader](http://axceler.com/products/sharepoint-products/fileloader/index).

Comment: Thanks, both of you! I was looking for a third-party tool, and FileLoader seems exactly what I'd need. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**A very welcome to the SharePoint world!**

I'm not sure if O3Spaces provides such ability by means of Web Services, which could help migrating the documents to SharePoint 2010, or a third-party tool for such purpose, at least I am unaware of.

Comment: It doesn't look like it does. I'll keep searching, though.